# data-modifying CTEs and triggers

Tags: postgresql, trigger, cte

If a data-modifying CTE inserts into two tables `t1` and `t2` that both have triggers, is there any guarantee on the order in which statement-level triggers are run?

```sql
-- t1 and t2 both have insert triggers
WITH do_insert_t1 AS (
  insert into t1 ... 
)
insert into t2 ...
```

I know that the [cte sub-statement execution order is not guaranteed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable.

and that triggers on the same table [fire alphabetically](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html)

> If more than one trigger is defined for the same event on the same relation, the triggers will be fired in alphabetical order by trigger name.

Is the order of "triggers on t1" vs "triggers on t2" also unpredictable?

(I am specifically interested in Postgres 12.)

Edit: clarified statement-level triggers specifically.

Comment: I would assume that you cannot rely on any specific order.